# how to return name and email from facebook using javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using facebook javascript SDK, and I have issues in getting the name and email.

When I console log my response it only consists of accessToken, expiresIn, signedRequest, userID. I tried switching to different versions but no luck.

Below is what I tried -

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {

    (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11&appId=myapp_id&autoLogAppEvents=1'; //used my app id
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'App_idd', //used my app id
          cookie     : true,
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.11' //also tried v2.4
        });

        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                //get needed fields
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

            } else {

            }
        });

    };

});
```

Comment: Did you get response while console.log ?

Comment: yes, as i said above my response consists of these fields accessToken,expiresIn,signedRequest,userID

Comment: read this, it explains everything you need to know: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Answer (score 0):

Use following function for email and get other fields from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api),

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'email'}, function(response) {
console.log(response);
});
```

**/me refers to current user.**

Comment: when should i call this? on login or? if i add this after fb.getloginStatus within the onload i get this error "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.", type: "OAuthException", code: 2500, fbtrace_id: "HFlvCcY+aOE""

Comment: After login grab the accessToken from response and pass to the function. Simply replace /me with  /accessTokenGoesHere

Comment: all my functions are inside document ready (onload) do i have to call fb.login on button login click ?

Comment: this not working FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                 var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                FB.api(accessToken, {fields: 'email'}, function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    });
                
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                
            } else {
                
            }
         });

Comment: i can get last_name but not email  {fields: 'name,id,last_name,email'} @Mayur

Comment: then you probably do not ask for the email with the scope parameter. and of coure you have to call FB.login on button click, or browsers will block it.

Comment: and do NOT replace /me with the token...you do not need to deal with the token while using the js sdk.

Comment: `FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,permissions', function(response) {
  console.log(response.name);
  console.log(response.email);
}`